# C# assign hotkey to a button

Tags: c#

Currently I want to add a hotkey to my button in C# windows application.

I went to the event, I didn't see anywhere I can assign hotkeys.

I wanna assign "F6' as the hotkey, which means whenever I press F6 it would trigger the button and run the code in it

Comment: WinForms. Also do you mind explaining to me what's the different between winform and WPF? I heard people use WPF to make the application looks better

Comment: The duplicate is correct but lacks of some key info. For example it doesn't give any advice on how to handle the same code in the button event and in the F6 handler.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to handle the Forms Keypress-event (and route all components keypress-events to that)

Assigning hotkeys via the GUI works just for MenuItems, if I'm not mistaken.

Edit: some code:

```
private void Form1_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyData == Keys.F6)
        button1_Click(this, new EventArgs());
}
```

Just what I quickly tried. If you register to the forms (or any other controls for that matter) KeyUp-event, you can query the released key and act accordingly. I suppose there are more elegant ways to do this, but this should get you started.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm kinda new to this. Could you explain it further, if possible give me some sample code 0 0

Comment: @Rain he did give you sample code.  The Form1_KeyUp function would be tied to an event handler for keypresses.  Check out this article http://codesamplez.com/development/wpf-hotkeys-c-sharp

Comment: Thank You very much, Figured it out, thx a lot~

Comment: Glad to hear it :-) An accept would be appreciated ;-) @MikeHometchko: I edited after he asked for it...

Comment: @lhiapgpeonk ah, didn't see the pre-edit.  Sorry!